# Emulate Mouse Movement with a HID device using python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mouseevent

I am trying to simulate mouse movements using a pi zero w as an HID device. I have simulated keyboard strokes with the pi, and I have successfully ran code that has sent keystrokes to the host computer the pi is attached to. Yet I don't understand how to simulate mouse movements, specifically when it comes to python3.

I follow the website below to mimic keystrokes:https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/

I use:

```
def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())
```

to send bytes from the pi to the host computer.

Is there any website that goes into detail of how to simulate mouse movements like the link above or is there a specific byte I can send to through the pi to simulate a mouse click/movement?

Comment: I have listed some resources here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393757/using-pi-zero-w-to-simulate-hid-keyboard-and-mouse but haven't cracked this yet