# Using Pi Zero W to simulate HID keyboard and mouse

Tags: usb, hid

My intention is to use a PiZeroW as an HID keyboard and mouse USB input device to computers.

I have consulted the following

- https://eleccelerator.com/tutorial-about-usb-hid-report-descriptors/ a good overview with links to usb.org's documentation
- https://eleccelerator.com/usbdescreqparser/ a parser to check the report file
- example code for hid keyboard, joystick, mouse https://github.com/msemtd/promicro-joypad/blob/master/HID.cpp
- also, http://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383

I thought I could just combine the keyboard and mouse descriptors into one file, adding REPORT_ID to each

```
0x05, 0x01,        // Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x06,        // Usage (Keyboard)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x85, 0x01,        //   Report ID (1)
0x05, 0x07,        //   Usage Page (Kbrd/Keypad)
0x19, 0xE0,        //   Usage Minimum (0xE0)
0x29, 0xE7,        //   Usage Maximum (0xE7)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //   Logical Maximum (1)
0x75, 0x01,        //   Report Size (1)
0x95, 0x08,        //   Report Count (8)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x81, 0x03,        //   Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x95, 0x05,        //   Report Count (5)
0x75, 0x01,        //   Report Size (1)
0x05, 0x08,        //   Usage Page (LEDs)
0x19, 0x01,        //   Usage Minimum (Num Lock)
0x29, 0x05,        //   Usage Maximum (Kana)
0x91, 0x02,        //   Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x75, 0x03,        //   Report Size (3)
0x91, 0x03,        //   Output (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x95, 0x06,        //   Report Count (6)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x65,        //   Logical Maximum (101)
0x05, 0x07,        //   Usage Page (Kbrd/Keypad)
0x19, 0x00,        //   Usage Minimum (0x00)
0x29, 0x65,        //   Usage Maximum (0x65)
0x81, 0x00,        //   Input (Data,Array,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              // End Collection
0x05, 0x01,        // Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x02,        // Usage (Mouse)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x09, 0x01,        //   Usage (Pointer)
0xA1, 0x00,        //   Collection (Physical)
0x85, 0x02,        //     Report ID (2)
0x05, 0x09,        //     Usage Page (Button)
0x19, 0x01,        //     Usage Minimum (0x01)
0x29, 0x03,        //     Usage Maximum (0x03)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //     Logical Maximum (1)
0x95, 0x03,        //     Report Count (3)
0x75, 0x01,        //     Report Size (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x75, 0x05,        //     Report Size (5)
0x81, 0x03,        //     Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //     Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x30,        //     Usage (X)
0x09, 0x31,        //     Usage (Y)
0x15, 0x81,        //     Logical Minimum (-127)
0x25, 0x7F,        //     Logical Maximum (127)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x02,        //     Report Count (2)
0x81, 0x06,        //     Input (Data,Var,Rel,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              //   End Collection
0xC0,              // End Collection

// 117 bytes
```

And then, it's a matter of setting up rc.local to automatically execute /usr/bin/isticktoit_usb, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir -p isticktoit
cd isticktoit
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB # USB2
#echo 0x1d6b > idVendor # Linux Foundation
#echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x2341 > idVendor # pretend leonardo
echo 0x8036 > idProduct # pretend leonardo
mkdir -p strings/0x409
echo "fedcba9876543210" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "pi zero w HID" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "iSticktoit.net USB Device" > strings/0x409/product
mkdir -p configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "Config 1: ECM network" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration
echo 250 > configs/c.1/MaxPower
# Add functions here
# see gadget configurations below
# End functions

# Add functions here
mkdir -p functions/hid.usb0
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length

echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xA1\\x01\\x85\\x01\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xE0\\x29\\xE7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x03\\x95\\x05\\x75\\x01\\x05\\x08\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x05\\x91\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x03\\x91\\x03\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x65\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x29\\x65\\x81\\x00\\xC0\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x02\\xA1\\x01\\x09\\x01\\xA1\\x00\\x85\\x02\\x05\\x09\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x03\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x95\\x03\\x75\\x01\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x05\\x81\\x03\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x30\\x09\\x31\\x15\\x81\\x25\\x7F\\x75\\x08\\x95\\x02\\x81\\x06\\xC0\\xC0 > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc


ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1/
# End functions

echo 0x80 > configs/c.1/bmAttributes
echo 200 > configs/c.1/MaxPower # 200 mA


ls /sys/class/udc > UDC

chown pi /dev/hidg0
sleep 3
```

The chown line is just to let user pi access the hidg0 port, with a test program such as

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time

time.sleep(3)

NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

# Press a
write_report(chr(2) + NULL_CHAR*2+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)

# Release keys
write_report(chr(2)+ NULL_CHAR*8)

# Press B
write_report(chr(2) + chr(32) + NULL_CHAR + chr(5)+NULL_CHAR*5)

# Release keys
write_report(chr(2) + NULL_CHAR*8)
```

The first character says the report is meant for REPORT_ID 2, i.e. the keyboard.

I was able to get the PZW to emulate a keyboard. But adding REPORT_ID and the mouse descriptor seems to make the emulation unrecognizable as a USB device.

The test program returns with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./composite.py", line 14, in <module>
    write_report(chr(2) + NULL_CHAR*2+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)
  File "./composite.py", line 11, in write_report
    fd.write(report.encode())
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 108] Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It seems that there is nothing really wrong with the set up. I added a "sleep 10" before the 'ls /sys/class/udc > UDC' line. I can now use the PI to talk HID keyboard and mouse commands to a computer.

Comment: I've added the same "sleep 10" but I still get the same error.

Comment: Hello @user1860288 how far you went with this project? I've some other project in my head and wondering if you got working code controlled raspberry as a mouse/keyboard. If you can, we can speak on https://discord.gg/sXZh53Qh

Answer (score 1):

This remains a good tutorial https://www.rmedgar.com/blog/using-rpi-zero-as-keyboard-setup-and-device-definition/

Here are the files I have used

(1) /usr/bin/isticktoit_usb

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir -p isticktoit
cd isticktoit
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB # USB2
#echo 0x1d6b > idVendor # Linux Foundation
#echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x2341 > idVendor # pretend leonardo
echo 0x8036 > idProduct # pretend leonardo
mkdir -p strings/0x409
echo "fedcba9876543210" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "pi zero w HID" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "iSticktoit.net USB Device" > strings/0x409/product
mkdir -p configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "Config 1: ECM network" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration
echo 250 > configs/c.1/MaxPower
# Add functions here
# see gadget configurations below
# End functions

# Add functions here
mkdir -p functions/hid.usb0
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length

echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x02\\xa1\\x01\\x09\\x01\\xa1\\x00\\x85\\x01\\x05\\x09\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x03\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x95\\x03\\x75\\x01\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x05\\x81\\x03\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x30\\x09\\x31\\x09\\x38\\x15\\x81\\x25\\x7f\\x75\\x08\\x95\\x03\\x81\\x06\\xc0\\xc0\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xa1\\x01\\x85\\x02\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x03\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x65\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x29\\x65\\x81\\x00\\xc0 > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc


ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1/
# End functions

echo 0x80 > configs/c.1/bmAttributes
echo 200 > configs/c.1/MaxPower # 200 mA

sleep 10

ls /sys/class/udc > UDC

sleep 2

chown pi /dev/hidg0

sleep 2
```

(2) test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time

time.sleep(3)

NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

# Press a
write_report(chr(2) + NULL_CHAR*2+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)

# Release keys
write_report(chr(2)+ NULL_CHAR*8)

# Press B
write_report(chr(2) + chr(32) + NULL_CHAR + chr(5)+NULL_CHAR*5)

# Release keys
write_report(chr(2) + NULL_CHAR*8)

# testing mouse
write_report(chr(1)+NULL_CHAR+chr(100)+chr(0)+NULL_CHAR)
time.sleep(2)
write_report(chr(1)+NULL_CHAR+chr(100)+chr(100)+NULL_CHAR)
time.sleep(2)
write_report(chr(1)+NULL_CHAR+chr(228)+chr(228)+NULL_CHAR)
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually a similar problem causing a BrokenPipeError, and the solution was very simple. Basically you need to plug the usb cable into the port that says USB on the rpi, and make sure this cable allows data transmission. This worked for me.