# How to emulate a HID device (mouse) on rPI Zero

Tags: usb, hid, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to get my RaspberryPi Zero to act as a USB mouse on my Macbook (OSX).
I followed this guide ([pi-zero as universal usb stick](https://www.raspberry-pi-geek.de/ausgaben/rpg/2020/04/pi-zero-als-universeller-usb-stick/)) Sorry, but it's a German guide.
As I understood it statse that I could use a Raspbian Lite which I flashed on my SD card with Raspbian Pi Manager (https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/).
I added

```
dtoverlay=dwc2
```

to the /boot/cmdline.txt
Then I installed git with

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

and finnaly I installed the git-project that provides the script to add the universal USB functionality:

```
git clone https://github.com/bablokb/raspi2go.git
cd raspi2go
sudo tools/install
```

I then rebooted with

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

But when I connect my RPI Zero with the data USB port (not the 5V USB port of course) I don't see any change regarding USB on my macbook.
I installed lsusb to see my connected USB devices

```
brew install lsusb
```

and then ran

```
lsusb -v
```

There is no change in the list of USB devices on my macbook.
So I figure that somehow something didn't work.
If it worked (adding USB storage device + USB serial device) I would have activated the HID functionality of the script and would have tried to follow the answer given here to get the mouse functionality:
[Emulate Mouse Movement with a HID device using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57280571/emulate-mouse-movement-with-a-hid-device-using-python)

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong?
I also tried to debug this, but I have no idea how to do this on my rPI.
I can login with ssh via Wifi, but on the console I'm not sure where I should start to see if things are working out.

I tried to see if I can find the endpoints that I can see in the script but I don't find something like functions/acm.USB0. I have limited know-how of Linux, so I'm not sure where exactly I would find these virtual devices that seem to be part of ConfigFS.
It would be great if somebody could tell me how I can debug this on the rPI side and on the mac.
Thanks in advance!

Juergen